# Filter by multiple values efficiently using crossfilter

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

I am working on a project where I am trying to build a dashboard using `crossfilter`. I am permitting users to filter the data by using select elements where each select element corresponds to one dimension.
In order to filter by multiple selected values for a specific dimension, I am using the `filterFunction()` method provided by `crossfilter`. However, `filterFunction()` loops through every value in the dimension and does not take advantage of the sort/bisecting functionalities.
Is there a better method to filter by multiple values so that the process becomes more efficient?
Thanks.

Comment: Does it actually cause a performance problem? Usually using filterFunction is not a big problem. If it is, integrating this functionality into the base Crossfilter library is being discussed here: https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/issues/60

Comment: @EthanJewett I am very new to Crossfilter, please forgive me. What I don't understand is, if the filtering is not incremental or more efficient, isn't the purpose of using Crossfilter defeated? I am using filterFunction() extensively in my code, it is the only filtering method I am using in my code. 
Thank you very much for responding!

Comment: No problem being new :-) If you use filterFunction, the group calculation is still incremental. However it does have to traverse the full list of dimension values to calculate the incremental filter.

Comment: @EthanJewett Thank you very much! :) I am able to understand how crossfilter carries out filtering from the code, but I am finding it hard to understand how the group calculation works. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Why don't you hop on the Crossfilter Gitter for "how it works" Q&A type stuff :-) It's linked from the main Github page and there are a bunch of people there who can help answer these sorts of questions.

Comment: Oh, I shall! Thank you very much! :)